# What does &str mean?

Tags: c, string

I have 3 doubts

First :

```
char str[25]="Catch";
printf("%d %s",&str,&str);
```

What will be the output?
In my opinion &str will give the memory address of the starting character of string, but using `%s`gives me the string `Catch` as the output?

Second:

What does this statement mean `&"Hello"`?

Third:

The following statement  `printf("%s",&str+n)` will give me what output?

Comment: Just see how & (address of) differs with arrays and other primitive data type. You will get the answers.

Comment: The ***&*** is the memory location of the beginning of the array.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Usually `&` takes the address of the storage, hence `&str` should get the address of symbol, or variable `str`, rather than the value of `str`, which is the beginning address of the array. I've seen similar questions a few times. This question deserves an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `&str` will produce a pointer to the entire `str` array. This pointer has type `char (*)[25]`. Naturally, its numerical value will point to the beginning of `str` in memory.

1. `printf("%d %s",&str,&str)`. The behavior of this `printf` call is undefined. Expression `&str` evaluates to a value of type `char (*)[25]`. Format specifier `%d` requires an argument of type `int`. `%s` specifier requires an argument of type `char *`. Passing arguments of incorrect (incompatible) type to `printf` causes undefined behavior.
2. `&"Hello"` is not a "statement". It is an expression, if anything. In expression `&"Hello"` operator `&` is applied to a string literal `"Hello"`, which is an array of type `char [6]`. The result is a pointer to that array. It has type `char (*)[6]`.
3. `printf("%s",&str+n)` triggers undefined behavior for the reasons described in 1.

Comment: Not so sure on the `%s` part.  `%s` does not require only `char *`, but  "the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type", alternate example: `unsigned char*`, Does not `char (*)[25]` meet "pointer to the initial element of an array of character"?

Comment: @chux: The standard wording is intended to cover both the type and the value of the supplied pointer. Just like the spec for `%d` in `fscanf` says that "The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer" does not mean that you can supply a `double *` pointer that just happens to point to an `int` object in memory, the above wording for `%s` in `fscanf` does not mean that you can supply a `char (*)[25]` pointer that happens to point to an initial character in an array.

Comment: What is not clear in the answer is how "pointer has type `char (*)[25]`" is not a "a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type".   The answer implies it must be a `char *`, yet that is not so.  It is a [pointer to array 25 of char](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*str%29%5B25%5D), so it is a pointer to an _array_ rather than the needed "pointer to the initial _element_ of an array ...".  That difference, not only invokes UB, but affects pointer arithmetic like `&str+n`.